# How to check attribute value with variable in selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

```html
<div class="aw-widgets-cellListCellTitleBlock">
  <h3 title="block1" class="aw-widgets-cellListCellTitle" id="CellTitle">block1</h3>
  <label class="aw-widgets-cellListCellItemType aw-base-small">000027</label>
</div>
```

In given snippet `title="block1"` i want to take it in the form of variable foe

e.g. `String sample="block1"` and then it used as `title=sample` or  `//div[text()=sample]`.

I tried this one but its not working. Did you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the title value from HTML code, then you can use any one from the following code.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'block1')]"));
```

or

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@id='CellTitle']"));
```

or

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='aw-widgets-cellListCellTitleBlock']/h3"));

 //get text
 String text = element.getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: element.getAttribute() returns string only. that doesn't mean hard coding.

Comment: <div class="" ng-show="showArrow">        <span ng-click="moveTabs($event)" class="aw-jswidget-controlArrow"></span>    </div>               I want this tag to be in the form of selector.What is the solution for it.

Comment: I didn't get you. What you want to get from these tag's?? is it fro same question that you posted or different??

Comment: no this one is different. I want value of above tag in the form of WebElement

Comment: ok..you can try this:  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='aw-jswidget-controlArrow']"));

Comment: Actually its not working what if tried with ng-show attribute?

Comment: yah...you can also use that no issue.

Comment: if i am passing string as String demoString="CellTitle"   then how can i modified this code                                                                             WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@id='CellTitle']"));

Comment: U have to use follwing code: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@id='"+demoString+"']"));